# .bind() example incorrect output

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind

I am learning about .bind() from the example on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Examples), the only changes that I've made to this example is where I added the console.log()'s.

```
this.x = 9;    // this refers to global "window" object here in the browser
var module = {
  x: 81,
  getX: function() { return this.x; }
};

console.log(module.getX()); // 81

var retrieveX = module.getX;
console.log(retrieveX());   
// returns 9 - The function gets invoked at the global scope

// Create a new function with 'this' bound to module
// New programmers might confuse the
// global var x with module's property x
var boundGetX = retrieveX.bind(module);
console.log(boundGetX()); // 81
```

Running this using Node I get,

```
$ node bind.js
81
undefined
81
```

The 'undefined' output should be '9'.

Why am I not getting that output?

Here's a screenshot from my attempt with Node:

[image]

Comment: it should work, I've just tried it. Are you running it in a browser?

Comment: No with node...

Comment: that's what I suspected  the example will only work in a browser

Comment: Please revert to the code sample. Screenshots have a lot of problems.

Comment: Oh!  Ok that is odd! So Javascript .bind() behaviour is different in Node that in the browser?

Comment: @ofey: No, `bind` isn't the difference; see my answer.

Comment: @ofey: It's important to include the **text** of the code and output you're getting, not just a picture. You'd done that quite correctly initially, but then your edit removed the text and replaced it with a picture. A picture can only be an adjunct, not a replacement, for the textual version. I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Running this using Node I get...

Because in NodeJS, your seemingly-top-level code isn't running at global scope and in it, `this` doesn't refer to the global object. All NodeJS code runs within a NodeJS *module*, which is not global scope. Since `this` doesn't refer to the global object, `this.x = 9;` doesn't create a property called `x` on it, and so when the unbound function is run with the wrong `this` (with `this` referring to the global object), it gets `undefined` instead of `9` for `this.x` property since there is no global property called `x`.

If you ran that code in a browser, it would do what MDN says it does. Alternately, you can change `this.x = 9;` to `global.x = 9;` and it will on NodeJS as well, because in NodeJS, `global` is a reference to the global object (just like `this` at global scope in browsers, and just like the `window` identifier in browsers).

You'll find that a lot of code examples which assume they're run at global scope will behave slightly differently when run in NodeJS, for this very reason. For instance, `var n;` at global scope creates a property on the global object, but `var n;` at the top-level of a NodeJS module just creates a variable scoped to that module, not a global.

Comment: Does this answer explain if/how the scope differs between lines 1 & 9? I'm not sure I follow that.

Comment: @JustinBlank: There's no scope difference between lines 1 & 9 in the posted code. For clarity, which lines do you mean?

Comment: line1: `this.x = 9`, line9: `console.log(retrieveX())`; If `this` in the function call refers to the same thing as line 1, shouldn't the result be `9`, regardless of whether `this` is global or the module?

Comment: @JustinBlank: I understand the question now. They're different `this`s. As I said at the outset, *"your seemingly-top-level code isn't running at global scope and in it, `this` doesn't refer to the global object"* A few minutes ago I beefed that up, and just beefed it up a bit more. Any better now?

Comment: So 'this' differs if you are in the browser or Node, as they show here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call Thanks

Comment: @ofey: At what seems like top-level scope, yes, because NodeJS is running your code as a module, not at global scope. (In fact, you *can't* run code at global scope with NodeJS.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, thanks. Top level code executes in the module scope, but an unbound function still executes in the global scope. Is that accurate?

Comment: @JustinBlank: No, the code in an unbound function called directly (like `retrieveX` above) is run in its own scope, but with `this` referring to the global object. People get confused on this a **lot**: `this` and scope have very, very little to do with each other. The scope in which `retrieveX`'s code is called can have literally **any** value for `this`, depending on how you call `retrieveX`. Just about the only relationship between `this` and scope is: 1. You can't change `this` *within* a scope (can't `this = newValue`), 2. Global scope's `this` will always refer to the global object.

Comment: I always had seen `this` referred to as dynamic scope. So in those terms, the dynamic scope is global, and the lexical scope is created inside of the function with the module as the parent.

Comment: @JustinBlank: Lots of people call `this` "scope," but as far as I can tell it's incorrect and it's certainly confusing. The specification just uses the term `thisArg`, which makes sense, as `this` really is just an argument to the function which is fixed at the point the function is called (or, as of ES2015, omitted in some cases -- arrow functions); nothing more. Lots of people also call `this` "context," but again, it's incorrect as far as I know and also confusing, because there *is* something in the spec called an execution context, which has virtually nothing to do with `this`. :-)

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. It's weird in some of the same ways as dynamic scope in languages that have it, but I think you're right that it isn't actually dynamic scope.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. Agreed! Referring  this as "scope" is definitely confusing, the "owner"/"host" maybe better?